# Are there any good Twilio iOS VOIP Client tutorials besides the ones provided by Twilio?

Tags: ios, voip, twilio

I'm trying to set up VOIP calling on iOS via the Twilio Client but struggling to set up the audio correctly. I've followed all of Twilio's tutorials and am able to connect calls but unable to hear audio. Are there any third-party tutorials that might help?

Comment: Twilio SDK has a known bug, in which audio call between simulator and device, mic in simulator doesn't work, where as other way works. Twilio support has confirmed the same.

Comment: @chandu have you any link for that or any document where twilio conformed this. then please provide that link.

Comment: @iPR its was an email communication with Twilio long back.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no tutorial for twillio like newboston or raywenderlich

you may start from here

http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/sms/sending-via-rest.

http://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/get-started-with-twilio-and-parse-in-the-twilio-cloud-module.html

Use github example projects and their documentations in order to understand